# Django use external postgresql database including File fields

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Django app and I need to separate the database (PostgreSQL) and put it in another server. My question is about file fields. I have some file fields in the model and it includes `models.FileField(upload_to='media/')`. Do files automatically will be uploaded to the database server or not?
thanks

Comment: Can you describe your question?

Comment: @Mayur I'm trying to find a way to upload File fields to another server apart from the server application located.

Answer (score 0):

Basically database only store the information about files i.e name, extesion, size etc but the actual file stored in the project media folder.
Location of the media folder depend what MEDIA_PATH you have set in django's settings.py.
So when you upload file then by default it goes to media folder that configured in setting file.
So you have to import the database and complete zip of project and make sure both media folder and static folder should be in the project.
Media Folder holds the uploaded files and static folder have the static files like css, js and other static images.
**An example of django project structure:-**

Myproject
 - myapp
 - myproject
 - static
 - media
 - manage.py

**In the setting file:-**
MEDIA_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Media path location of media folder
media_url is that will be used in template to show images or media on front

I hope you will get your answer here.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to upload files to the second server?